# ¿como colocar background de video o fondo de video en pyqt5?(python3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QBrush, QPixmap,QImage
from PyQt5 import uic
import PIL
from PIL import *
from PIL import ImageQt
import imageio
import time
video_name = "C:/Users/quico/Desktop/stri/striming/resursos/videos/video3.mp4" #This is your video file path
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)
def bucle():
    while True:
        stream()
def stream():
    for image in video.iter_data():
        im=Image.fromarray(image)
        img=im.resize((600,400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        pal=ImageQt.ImageQt(img)
        pal2=QImage(pal)
        rex=QPixmap.fromImage(pal2)
        w=QDialog()

#Clase heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventanas)
class Ventana(QDialog):

 #Método constructor de la clase
     def __init__(self):
  #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
         QDialog.__init__(self)
  #Cargar la configuración del archivo .ui en el objeto
         uic.loadUi("diseño1.ui", self)
         self.setWindowTitle("Cambiando el título de la ventana")


#Instancia para iniciar una aplicación
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
bucle()
#Mostra la ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar la aplicación
app.exec_()
```

hola buenas 
estoy haciendo una aplicación con el entorno qt y Python estoy ocupando como entorno de desarrollo de la interfaz grafica el qt designer 
pero me e encontrado con el inconveniente de que no logro colocar un video como fondo de pantalla, por que quiero colocar un video por que este video tiene una animación de por medio y le queda ben a la interfas grafica

se me ocurrió descomponer el video en imágenes y colocárselas en secuencia como fondo de pantalla al qt
pero el programa se me queda pegado y no funciona 
si alguien me puede ayudar por favor

aquí esta el diseño que realice 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mostrar el contenido de diseño1.ui

Comment: ya lo modifique hay puedes ver el diseño que realice

Comment: ¿Quieres que el vídeo se muestre como fondo, o solo se reproduzca en una parte?

Comment: que se muestre como fondo en la aplicacion

Comment: He probado tu teoria, cuando no hay ningun widget funciona genial pero si se le añade algun .ui lo hace lento, estoy pensando en otra idea, pero no usare el .ui sino añadire los widgets directamente. He pensado usar QVideoWidget y colocar encima los widgets.

Comment: ¿Por que usas QDialog? ¿podrias usar QWidget?

Comment: se me hacia mas fácil de ejecutar antes de colocar el fondo de pantalla de la aplicación

Comment: No es tanto por ello, sino que ciertas acciones hacen que se repinte el fondo por ejemplo el movimiento del mouse, cuando mueves la ventana, redimensionas, etc, y eso tiene un costo por lo que conlleva a que la aplicacion se muestre lenta, te voy a pasar el codigo en unos momentos y veras el problema.

Comment: okey estare esperando su código